# Join lines based on pattern

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, solaris

I have the following file:

```
test
1
My
2
Hi
3
```

i need a way to use cat ,grep or awk to give the following output:

```
test1
My2
Hi3
```

How can i achieve this in a single command? something like

```
cat file.txt | grep ... | awk ...
```

Note that its always a string followed by a number in the original text file.

Comment: you want odd-numbered lines only? or lines that do not start with numbers?

Comment: Grep is not an appropriate tool for this task. Use either sed or awk.

Comment: how can i do this with awk or sed?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`sed 'N;s/\n//' file.txt`

This should give the desired output when the content is in file.txt

Answer (score 3):

```
paste -d "" - - < filename
```

This takes consecutive lines and pastes them together delimited by the empty string.

Answer (score 2):

```
awk '{printf("%s", $0);} !(NR%2){printf("\n");}' file.txt
```

---

**EDIT**: I just noticed that your question requires the use of `cat` and `grep`. Both of those programs are unnecessary to achieve your stated aims. If you have some reason for including them that you haven't mentioned, try this (uselessly inefficient) version of the line I wrote immediately above:

```
cat file.txt | grep '^' | awk '{printf("%s", $0);} !(NR%2){printf("\n");}'
```

It is possible that this command uses features not present in the original `awk` program. You may need to invoke the new awk program, `nawk` instead.

Comment: i had a syntax error when doing cat file.tx | awk '{printf("%s", $0);} !(NR%2){printf("\n");}'

Comment: 1) What, precisely, was the error message?  2) What shell do you use?

Comment: i am using bash on solaris. the error mesages are awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1

Comment: Sorry, don't have Solaris handy. This works with GNU Awk on Linux.

Comment: First, you're wasting a process when adding 'cat'.  Awk is perfectly capable of reading a file as STDIN.  Second, the use of 'grep' is superflous --- 'awk' is designed to do the matching.  Third, IIRC, Solaris may need 'nawk'.

Comment: @James_R_Ferguson - 1) and 2): You know that. I know that. See the first line of my answer. The problem is that the OP specifically asked for a solution of the form `cat file.txt | grep ... | awk ...`. I'll update to make the irony more clear. 3) Thanks.

Comment: On Solaris, use `/usr/bin/nawk` or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` instead of (what is often described as "the old, broken") `/usr/bin/awk`

Answer (score 0):

If your input file is always 1 number then 1 string, and you only want the strings, all you have to do is take every other line.

If you only want the odd lines, you can do `awk 'NR % 2' file.txt`

If you want the evens, this becomes `awk 'NR % 2==0' data`

Comment: Ah, misread the question, ignore this then, Sujoy has a great answer

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer:
`cat file.txt | awk 'BEGIN { lno = 0 } { val=$0; if (lno % 2 == 1) {printf "%s\n", $0} else {printf "%s", $0}; ++lno}'`