# Using sed Command

Tags: bash, sed, solaris

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Join lines based on pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8156137/join-lines-based-on-pattern)

I have the following file:

```
test 
one 
My
two 
Hi
three
```

i need a way to use cat and sed to give the following output:

```
testone
Mytwo
Hithree
```

How can i achieve this in a single command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where the file "foo.txt" contains your text:

```
cat foo.txt | sed -e 'N;s/\n//'
```

Comment: Should this read `sed -e '$!N;s/\n//'`?

Comment: clear out empty lines if you have any else it wont work